# White space at the right and bottom edge of the window

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

After I created a window, which should be completely black, there are white colors at the right and bottom edges. What is it that I may be doing wrong ?

this is the constructor where I do initialisation of window :-

```
    public Panel()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gameWidth, gameHeight));
        JFrame f = new JFrame("AlienBusters");
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        t.start();
    }
```

this is the paint method where I made the window black :-

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);
    }
```

Comment: Don't call your class "Panel". There is an AWT component with that class name and it is confusing. Your class name should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five things...

1. Calling `setResizable` after `pack`, not a good idea, `setResizable` can change the frame border size, which affects the available content size...
2. Using `KeyListener`, seriously, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and save youreself the head ache...
3. Relying on magic numbers instead of imperical values, `g.fillRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight);` should be `g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` or better, simply use `setBackground(Color.BLACK)` and get it for free via `super.paintComponent`...and `paintComponent` should be `protected` ;)
4. Calling `setPreferredSize`.  This means that the size could be changed, which, probably, isn't what you really want.  Instead, override `getPreferredSize` instead.  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details
5. Constructing a frame within the constructor of a component, the component shouldn't care how it's going to be displayed, it should just focus on it's job.